# Something wrong creating a named set

Tags: ssms, mdx

I am creating a named set in SSMS with this code:

```
WITH SET [American WWII Figures] AS
'{[American GI], [US Army Pilot]}'
```

and i get the respons:

```
Executing the query ...
Parser: The end of the input was reached.

Execution complete
```

Is that query succefully executed?

When i then try to use the named set with:

```
SELECT {[American WWII Figures]} ON COLUMNS,
        [Year].Members ON ROWS
FROM    [Max Min Manufacturing DM]  
WHERE [Measures].[Total Products]
```

i get:

```
Executing the query ...
Query (1, 9) The dimension '[American WWII Figures]' was not found in the cube
when the string, [American WWII Figures], was parsed.
```

Execution complete

Since it doesn´t appear to exist i guess something is wrong when i create the set. What could be the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about different ways to make named sets in mdx. Either with the "CREATE SET.." or like me: WITH SET.

I learned that the difference are the scope it exists. When you use the WITH-statement the named set only exists in the query. I executed the queries at different times but when i ran them together everything worked fine!

Comment: Yep, that's how it works. If you want it permanently, you can define it in the cube calculation script (Assuming you use SSAS?). Depending on which version of MDX you use, you can also have 'session scoped' sets and members, which would have worked in your above example (I think in SSAS it would have been CREATE SET instead of WITH SET?)